# Postgres (running under docker) query 10X slower on EC2 as compared to home PC with same config

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, query-optimization

I am encountering a puzzling scenario where the same PostgreSQL query is exhibiting a significant difference in execution time between two similar environments, a `c3.2xlarge` EC2 instance (8 cores, 16GB RAM) and a `home PC` (4 cores, 16GB RAM).

Both the machines are freshly rebooted and no background activities are happening.

Despite the EC2 instance having more cores, the query runs much faster on the home PC.

**Home PC:**

Cores: 4 cores (Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-9100F CPU @ 3.60GHz)

Ram:

```
        total   used   free   shared buff/cache  available
Mem:     15Gi  4.3Gi  339Mi  315Mi     10Gi        10Gi
Swap:    2.0Gi  1.9Gi  75Mi
```

Disk:

```
$ sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda3
/dev/sda3:
Timing cached reads:  31068 MB in 1.98 seconds = 15667.13 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 978 MB in 3.00 seconds = 325.47 MB/sec
```

**EC2:**

Cores: 8 cores (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80GHz)
Ram:

```
       total   used   free   shared buff/cache  available
Mem:   14Gi  355Mi  193Mi    186Mi   14Gi        13Gi
Swap:  0B 0B 0B
```

Disk:  (io2, 5000 IOPS)

```
/dev/xvdf1:
Timing cached reads:  18328 MB in 1.99 seconds = 9214.44 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 614 MB in 3.00 seconds = 204.56 MB/sec
```

Postgres (postgres:15.1-alpine) on both the instances are running using docker and hence are exactly the same.

Below is the explain analyze:

**EC2:**

```
postgres=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) select count(*) from customer;
QUERY PLAN  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Finalize Aggregate (cost=10098.84..10098.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=264.979..268.988 rows=1 loops=1)
    Output: count(*)
    Buffers: shared hit=1059
    -> Gather (cost=10098.63..10098.84 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=263.757..268.974 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=1059
        -> Partial Aggregate (cost=9098.63..9098.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=247.744..247.747 rows=1 loops=3)
            Output: PARTIAL count(*)
            Buffers: shared hit=1059
            Worker 0: actual time=239.843..239.847 rows=1 loops=1
              Buffers: shared hit=330
            Worker 1: actual time=239.939..239.942 rows=1 loops=1
              Buffers: shared hit=329
            -> Parallel Index Only Scan using idx_phone on customer (cost=0.42..8603.71 rows=197968 width=0) (actual time=0.028..126.421 rows=158374 loops=3)
                Output: phone
                Heap Fetches: 0
                Buffers: shared hit=1059
                Worker 0: actual time=0.032..122.257 rows=152827 loops=1
                  Buffers: shared hit=330
                Worker 1: actual time=0.031..122.544 rows=152567 loops=1
                  Buffers: shared hit=329
Query Identifier: -8199084466783743761
Planning:
Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.109 ms
Execution Time: 269.051 ms
(28 rows)
```

**Home PC:**

```
postgres=# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE) select count(*) from customer;
QUERY PLAN 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Finalize Aggregate (cost=10116.12..10116.13 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=22.262..24.016 rows=1 loops=1)
    Output: count(*)
    Buffers: shared hit=1152
    -> Gather (cost=10115.90..10116.11 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=22.162..24.009 rows=3 loops=1)
        Output: (PARTIAL count(*))
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=1152
        -> Partial Aggregate (cost=9115.90..9115.91 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=16.569..16.570 rows=1 loops=3)
            Output: PARTIAL count(*)
            Buffers: shared hit=1152
            Worker 0: actual time=14.152..14.152 rows=1 loops=1
              Buffers: shared hit=310
            Worker 1: actual time=14.204..14.205 rows=1 loops=1
              Buffers: shared hit=311
            -> Parallel Index Only Scan using idx_phone on customer (cost=0.42..8620.85 rows=198020 width=0) (actual time=0.043..10.313 rows=158409 loops=3)
                Output: phone
                Heap Fetches: 183
                Buffers: shared hit=1152
                Worker 0: actual time=0.038..8.724 rows=144123 loops=1
                  Buffers: shared hit=310
                Worker 1: actual time=0.033..8.725 rows=144978 loops=1
                  Buffers: shared hit=311
Query Identifier: -4988056339636578098
Planning:
Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.187 ms
Execution Time: 24.152 ms
(28 rows)
```

As can be seen the different is a whooping 10X!!

P.S: We originally found the issue on our t3 instance (gp3) image, so we thought of using a better instance and were surprised to see the same difference!

P.P.S: We ruled out https://www.heap.io/blog/running-a-database-on-ec2-your-clock-could-be-slowing-you-down because our clocksource is set to `tsc`

Comment: Your home PC is much faster, see the Index Only Scan that is 10 times faster and consumes almost all time needed for this query. Looks like a difference in CPU and/or RAM since all data is collected from memory.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, agreed that the CPU types are different, but the RAM size is the same, in fact EC2 has double the cores. Still does it warrant a 10X difference?

Comment: See what [`pgbench`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html) thinks of either of these systems when you hit them with the built-in scripts. If your query uses 2 workers it doesn't matter much that one system has 8 and the other 4 at disposal, especially if you're claiming these are 1:1 clones of the same db, same config, same [`max_worker_processes`, `max_parallel_workers`, `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`, `parallel_leader_participation`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-ASYNC-BEHAVIOR).

Comment: A heavily oversimplified take on this could be that since it's pretty much just a long read operation, if the 12-year-old server turns out to be 2x slower disk-to-RAM compared to the 5-year-old laptop, then 2x slower RAM-to-CPU, then the CPU performs 2x worse, then according to my abacus that's your 2*2*2=8x difference right there.

Comment: The core count beyond 3 doesn't matter, as you aren't using them. Probably due to max_parallel_workers_per_gather being low, or maybe for some other reason.  Anyway the "vCPU" reported by AWS are not real cores. For x86, 8 vCPU means 4 actually useful independent means of execution.